# Hong Kong restaurant apps/websites

Tags: online-resources, hong-kong, restaurants, mobile-apps

What are the good websites/apps that tell us about eating out options in Hong Kong? Reviews, Menus, cost, etc.

Comment: What kind of budget are you looking at? For the higher end, the Michelin guide is probably a good starting point.

Comment: Surprisingly, many of the Michelin spots in HK are very affordable.

Answer (score 4):

Among locals in Hong Kong, [OpenRice](https://www.openrice.com/en/hongkong) would be the most popular website/app for that purpose. There are reviews, photos, menu etc. about the restaurant.

The website/app have Chinese and English user interface, but since the user population is mainly Chinese speaker, so the reviews are usually in Chinese, which might not be so helpful for you. Don't expect menu will always be available and up-to-date, the user community may take photos of the menu and upload it to the site, but it will always be a good idea to take a look at the menu before dinning there.

Answer (score 0):

Travel Expert City Guides have created an iOS travel app that includes restaurants, hotels, activities and shopping. They have a range of cities including Hong Kong. For the HK app click [here](https://itunes.apple.com/app/hong-kong-travel-expert-guides-maps-navigation/id1093796498?mt=8). For the other cities click [here](https://itunes.apple.com/developer/travel-expert-city-guides-ltd/id641051340).